# How to postpone an event in Spark/RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, spark-streaming

We are designing a system that will stream event using RabbitMQ (maybe later kafka) and spark streaming. Some or our events have been broken to several event types, so not to have too big of an event. This means that certain events have to wait for the other events (with the same id). We cannot proceed with processing until all events for a specific event have arrived.

Is there a way to delay the processing of an event until the next processing window in spark streaming (if the other event has not arrived)

Thank
Nir

Comment: i use rabbitmq for a different purpose so this may or may not be helpful,look into DLX(dead-letter-exchange) you could delay by publishing into this queue and when they arrive again you could proceed to deciding if they should or should not be processed again.

Comment: This is how I understood this: You have event A with id 78; you are splitting event A into eventA1, eventA2..eventAn; ou can't process eventAn until eventAn-1 has been processed. If this is correct, why split eventA in the first place? YOu say it's big, what does this mean? To slow for network transport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an architectural perspective, there are questions to consider:

- how do you determine that all events have arrived?
- what happens if one event gets lost?
- what happens if events arrive out of order? Last first and similar?

In principle it would seem that breaking down an event in parts that was originally formed as a whole would increase the complexity and affect the reliability of the system.

To answer to the question in any case, since Spark 1.6.x a new stateful streaming function has been introduced: `mapWithState`. `mapWithState` allows you to keep state information per key and issue zero or more events of the same or different type in response to an incoming event.

Applied to this case, we could think of modelling the state as `State[PartialEvent]`: as events come in, they are assembled in a `PartialEvent` object. Once the criteria that an event is complete has been fulfilled, mapWithState can generate a `WholeEvent` object to be processed downstream.

The process would roughly(*) look like this:

```
val sourceEventDStream:DStream[Event] = ???
def stateUpdateFunction(eventId:String, event: Event, partialEventState: State[PartialEvent]): Option[WholeEvent] = {
    val eventState = partialEventState.get()  // Get current state of the event
    val updatedEvent = merge(eventState, event)
    if (updatedEvent.isComplete) {
       partialEventState.remove()
       Some(WholeEvent(updatedEvent)) 
    }  else {
       partialEventState.update(updatedEvent)
       None
    }          
}
val wholeEventDStream:DStream[WholeEvent] = sourceEventDStream.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(stateUpdateFunction))
//do stuff with wholeEventDStream ...
```

As you could observe, with this approach, any `PartialEvent` that never completes will stay in the state forever. We also need a unique key to identify events that belong together. There're timeout options that must be considered to cover for the failure cases, but the bottom line is that preserving a whole event through the pipeline would be a better approach, if technically possible.

---

(*) not compiled or tested. Provided only to illustrate the idea.